# Alchemy News Excerpts

Tags: ibm-watson, alchemyapi

We are formatting and presenting Alchemy Data News query results for our users. I think I see other demos that do this (e.g. Watson News Explorer) and they display a small excerpt from each article. I don't see any excerpts returned by Alchemy Data News API. Are we missing something in our query? How can we display an excerpt of the news story for our users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve a text sample using **return=enriched.url.text**

See a full list of parameters here

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wN0e_fhYCO7GBAneN9xjrNo57OtS_0Tr8FI9xCMfmzM/edit#gid=0

for example

```
https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/data/GetNews?apikey=****
  &outputMode=json&start=now-1d&end=now&count=100
  &q.enriched.url.enrichedTitle.relations.relation
  =|action.verb.text=acquire,object.entities.entity.type=Company|
  &return=enriched.url.text
```

will return

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "usage": "By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html",
    "totalTransactions": "148",
    "result": {
        "docs": [
            {
                "id": "NzI0MTkzMTM0N3wxNDY0OTYzMzY2",
                "source": {
                    "enriched": {
                        "url": {
                            "text": "We've heard all year that fighting
                             the opioid crisis is the most important issue facing the New Hampshire
                             Legislature. Executive Councilor Colin Van Ostern is required by law to
                             file a report on his gubernatorial campaign's receipts and expenditures by
                             June 22. ..."
                        }
                    }
                },
                "timestamp": 1464963366
            },(...)
```

ps. I am using Alchemy API for Bluemix